# How To Solve CreatedAtAction That Returns "No route matches the supplied values."

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing

Hi folks I have a problem with using `CreateAtAction` in asp .net 8 api when I need to use it in my post or put request to go to a get request  I have tried to make too many things to solve it by adding

`[ActionName(nameof([Your Action Name]))]`

or to add a Name to the HttpGet Notation

`[HttpGet("{variable}" , Name =nameof([Your Action Name]))]`

or like this

`[HttpGet("{variable}" , Name ="[Unique name]")]`

also i make the two together like this

```
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AreaController : ControllerBase
{
    //     [HttpGet("{variable}" , Name =nameof([Your Action Name]))]
    //or
    //     [HttpGet("{variable}" , Name ="[Unique name]")] 
    //and
    //     [ActionName(nameof([Your Action Name]))]
    public async Task<ActionResult<YourClass>> GetSomething(int variable)
    {
    }
    
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<YourClass>> PostSomething(YourClass pass)
    {
    //    return CreatedAtAction(nameof([Your Action Name]), new { variable = pass.Id });
    //or
    //    return CreatedAtAction("[Unique name]", new { variable = pass.Id });
    //or
    //    return CreatedAtAction(nameof([Your Action Name]), new { variable = pass.Id },pass);
    //or
    //    return CreatedAtAction("[Unique name]", new { variable = pass.Id },pass);
    }
}
```

**note :** this when I pass this `([Wherever], new { variable = pass.Id },pass)` it return the `pass`  object  not going to the Get request

[image]

[image]

Otherwise the problem still occurs

[image]

I tried those techniques

[No route matches the supplied values](https://www.josephguadagno.net/2020/07/01/no-route-matches-the-supplied-values)

[ASP.NET Core: CreatedAtAction - No route matches the supplied values](https://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2021/07/aspnet-core-createdataction-no-route.html)

[Getting System.InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values. while using CreatedAtAction](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnet-api-versioning/issues/601)

Comment: What does *"it return the pass object not going to the Get request"* mean?  I get the impression that you've made it run without exception in that case but your expectations as to what the response should look like are wrong.

Comment: The key component of a 201 response is the `Location` header. A response body is optional and its contents are merely supplemental.

Comment: as my understanding the  CreatedAtAction work as RedirectToAction but the Difference is the request return 201 in the header but the RedirectToAction returns 302
I don't know if my idea about it is correct and correct me if I was wrong 
when the CreatedAtAction  works the request will return 201 and It will be redirected to the Get Method and the get method will return the result 
this is what i know about it 
Excuse me for my English, it is not my mother tongue 

Comment: Very wrong. 201 is not a redirect. It is a success status, like 200. The difference is that it includes the `Location` header to tell you where the resource that it created can be found. The presence of a `Location` header is not always a redirect. Only the 3xx series of response codes, and only the subset of them that are defined as redirects, are redirects.

Comment: CreatedAtAction(nameof([Your Action Name]), new { variable = pass.Id },pass)  in this for example when the endpoint is called the I am Expect to that the result from the get endpoint returned but the (pass) object is the actual result of the Response  so this what I mean by that   the idea for all this is I need the post or put endpoint after it job done takes the the id of the object and make the get endpoint that has id as parameter works and take the id from the post or the out endpoints and return the object and his information and in the header the Stat 201 is that possible in any way ?!!

Comment: No. Your expectations are all wrong. All `CreateAtAction` does is return a 201 response with a `Location` header built from the route values and the object passed for the `value` parameter serialized and written as the response body (usually as JSON).  *That's it.*  If you want the get that resources, you have to make an entirely separate GET request using the URI from the `Location` header.

Comment: Well thanks my friend, after that, I feel so stupid, I'm new to the API so I appreciate your kindness and thanks for your patience